# For CSS font family property, setting Initial or not setting are same?

Tags: css

I have a scenario, where html body set to one font family, but i dont want this font style to apply on one of the div element. how can i do this?.
i used font-family:initial; is this correct?

Comment: Did you actually try it?

Answer (score 0):

`font-family:initial` will set font-family property to its default value.
Try this way

```
div{
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

div[name="div1" ]{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

here all the div elements font-family property is set to **Times New Roman** except the div element named **div1**